# Display pandas dataframe duplicates based on one column then keep based on a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Afternoon,

I have duplicates (id and ticker combination) in my df which I would like to display then remove based on criteria in another column. I have seen a number of sorting solutions but would prefer to resolve this by filtering.

```
    display(df)     
        
    id  ticker              state
396219  ACGB 3 1/4 04/21/29 Ended
396496  NULL                Done
396496  ACGB 5 3/4 05/15/21 Done
396521  ACGB 4 1/2 04/15/20 Ended
396523  ACGB 1 3/4 11/21/20 Ended
396581  TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Order Sent
396588  TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Order Sent
396588  TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Done
396680  KBN 3.4 07/24/28    Done
```

1. Display all duplicates for information purposes.

> ```
> id        ticker              state
> 396588    TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Order Sent
> 396588    TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Done
> ```
>
> I tried  df[df.duplicated(['id','ticker'])]) but it shows all rows

2. For each set of duplicates only keep the one where df['state'] == 'Done'

> ```
>     id        ticker          state
> 396588    TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Done
> ```

3. Display all the original data, without the duplicates i.e. unique id.ticker records

> ```
> 396219    ACGB 3 1/4 04/21/29 Ended
> 396496    NULL                Done
> 396496    ACGB 5 3/4 05/15/21 Done
> 396521    ACGB 4 1/2 04/15/20 Ended
> 396523    ACGB 1 3/4 11/21/20 Ended
> 396581    TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Order Sent
> 396588    TCV 5 1/2 11/15/18  Done
> 396680    KBN 3.4 07/24/28    Done
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to order your dataframe with `status` equals "Done" rows at the top. Then remove duplicates by `id` and `ticker`.

This does reorder your data, but you can reorder by `id` via `sort_values` at the end, if required.

Here's one way:

```
# bring Done rows to top
res = pd.concat([df[df['state'] == 'Done'], df[df['state'] != 'Done']])

# drop duplicates and sort by id
res = res.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'ticker'])\
         .sort_values('id')\
         .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

       id            ticker      state
0  396219  ACGB31/404/21/29      Ended
1  396496               NaN       Done
2  396496  ACGB53/405/15/21       Done
3  396521  ACGB41/204/15/20      Ended
4  396523  ACGB13/411/21/20      Ended
5  396581   TCV51/211/15/18  OrderSent
6  396588   TCV51/211/15/18       Done
7  396680    KBN3.407/24/28       Done
```

Comment: Hi @jpp is there a way to do this without sorting? Ideally I would like to select and exclude using filters.

Comment: @PeterLucas, Probably, but I'd rather someone else post that solution. In my opinion, sorting is far better than filtering by row.

Comment: @PeterLucas, Fyi, I've updated to include `sort_values` to match your desired output. If you want to avoid sorting, this should have been stated in your question.

Comment: @jpp - why `res = pd.concat([df[df['state'] == 'Done'], df[df['state'] != 'Done']])` ? Absolutely redundant in my opinion

Comment: @jezrael, To get the Done rows to the top. I could have sorted, but I don't know what other values he has in that column. Could also convert to categorical and reorder categories to put Done first. Lots of ways. Please post your own answer and OP can accept that one if it suits better.

Comment: Hi Guys, the state has many strings i.e Accepted, Cancelled, Done etc. Thats why I was looking to filter as opposed to sort